# perl command line interpreter has stopped working in Windows 7

Tags: windows, perl

When I am trying to run perl script on my machine, `perl.exe` crashes, and I get the following message

```
[Window Title]
Perl Command Line Interpreter

[Main Instruction]
Perl Command Line Interpreter has stopped working

[Content]
Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.

[^] Hide problem details  [Check online for a solution and close the program] [Close the program] [Debug the program]
```

Problem signature:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   perl.exe
Application Version:    5.8.6.811
Application Timestamp:  41bdd6f7
Fault Module Name:  MSVCRT.dll
Fault Module Version:   7.0.7600.16930
Fault Module Timestamp: 4eeaf834
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   00009b60
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Does anyone know what is causing this error?

Comment: What perl distribution are you using, e.g. cygwin, ActiveState Perl, Strawberry Perl?

Comment: You're using a version of Perl that's a decade old. It's not even close to the latest of that version of Perl. What exactly do you expect from us?

Comment: @ikegami just `use v5.16.0` :)

Answer (score 1):

Judging from Google search of the terms "msvcrt.dll" and "perl", it appears that you are using ActiveState Perl.

In the [ActivePerl FAQ](http://community.activestate.com/faq/activeperl-supported-windows-7), it is claimed that

> For 5.8, ActivePerl builds 827 or higher have been tested on Windows 7 and Server 2008R2.

So it's possible that your version (build 811) doesn't work in Windows 7.

A reasonable step to take is to simply install a newer version of ActivePerl.

Comment: Thank you! Installing latest version of Perl fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to my issue with old Altera/cygwin under Windows 10. Some newer exploit protection causes problems. I have to disable at least SEHOP for several programs. (SEHOP = Structured Exception Overwrite Protection).